# How can I extract a specific part of a JSON file?

Tags: java, android, json

This is my JSON file :

```
  {  
     "coord":{  
        "lon":139,
        "lat":35
     },
     "weather":[  
        {  
           "id":803,
           "main":"Clouds",
           "description":"broken clouds",
           "icon":"https://cdn.glitch.com/6e8889e5-7a72-48f0-a061-863548450de5%2F04n.png?1499366020983"
        }
     ],
     "base":"stations",
     "main":{  
        "temp":7,
        "pressure":1025,
        "humidity":75,
        "temp_min":7,
        "temp_max":7
     },
     "visibility":10000,
     "wind":{  
        "speed":5.1,
        "deg":100
     },
     "clouds":{  
        "all":75
     },
     "dt":1549794600,
     "sys":{  
        "type":1,
        "id":8024,
        "message":0.0034,
        "country":"JP",
        "sunrise":1549748122,
        "sunset":1549786891
     },
     "id":1851632,
     "name":"Shuzenji",
     "cod":200
  }
```

I have tried to extract the `weather` array but it doesn't work.

```
        JSONArray mArray;
        try {
            mArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject mJsonObject = mArray.getJSONObject(i);
                txtJson.append(mJsonObject.getString("weather"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //txtJson.setText(result);
        }

        txtJson.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: You need to learn clearly what is JSON Object and what is JSON Array. I suggest you to do some google and i believe you can solve this problem by yourself.

Comment: You can use GSON or other libraries to handle all the hard parts for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you expect that code to do, but if you want to extract the weather array, this is how you do it.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray weather = json.getJSONArray("weather");
```

Then you can get individual entries in the array

```
JSONObject entry = weather.getJSONObject(0);
int id = entry.getInt("id");
String main = entry.getString("main");
```

or if you just want to turn the array back to a string

```
String s = weather.toString();
```